# Proof review: Every maximal ideal of ring of continuous functions has the same form

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be the ring of real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$. If $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ prove $\exists \lambda \in [0,1]$ s.t. $M = \{f(x) \in R : f(\lambda) = 0 \}$. (from Herstein Topics in Algebra)

My attempt: For contradiction assume $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ but $\exists m, m' \in M$ s.t. $m$ and $m'$ vanish at different points if at all. We'll prove that this implies $M = R$, a contradiction, so *all* $m, m' \in M$ must vanish at the same point.

Because $m, m' \in M$, $m^2, m'^2 \in M$ as well. $m^2$ and $m'^2$ are two non-negative continuous functions in $M$ s.t. $m'^2 (\lambda) = 0 \rightarrow m^2 (\lambda) \neq 0$ and vice versa. Because $M$ is an ideal, $m^2 + m'^2 \in M$ as well. $m^2 + m'^2$ is *strictly* positive and, like every element of $R$, bounded. Therefore the continuous function $f = \frac{1}{m^2 + m'^2}$ exists in $R$. So $f \cdot (m^2 + m'^2) \in M$, so $1 \in M$, so $M = R$.

Please let me know if this proof works and thank you in advance.

Comment: You didn't get the negation of what you're trying to prove right - for a contradiction you should be assuming that for every $\lambda\in[0,1]$ there exists $m\in M$ with $m(\lambda\ne0$. Now a proof very much like what you did leads to a contradiction. (To see why what you assumed is not the same, consider $\{a,b\}$, $\{b,c\}$ and $\{a,c\}$. The intersection of any two is nonempty but the intersection of all three is empty...)